# Python Code in Airflow Dag

Tags: python

I have a python code in Airflow Dag. This Dag performs 3 tasks:

1. Authenticate the user and get access token
2. Create a Databricks cluster using rest API and Submit a notebook job on a cluster using rest API. Pass access token created in the first step as input.
3. Check the status of notebook job

Please help me with code review for this Airflow Dag.

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import json
import os
import requests
import time
import logging


auth_file = "my-token.txt"
idds_cluster_id_file = "my-cluster-id.txt"
path = "/airflow/tokens/"
cluster_id = "0408-000631"
path= "/airflow/tokens/"
temp_run_id_file = "my_save_run_id.txt"
databeicks_token_file= "databricks-token.txt"
auth_url = "https://snapdeal.com/authentication"
cluster_url = "https://snapdeal.com/clustermanager"
exec_url = "https://snapdeal.com/databricksexecutor"

args = {
    'owner': "airflow",
    'start_date': datetime.now()
}
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="my-notebook-job-trigger-dev",
    default_args=args,
    max_active_runs=1,
    concurrency=1
)
status_dict = {
    "action": "get_job_status"
    }
auth_dict = {
    "refresh_token": ""
}

cluster_dict = {
    "payload": {
        "cluster_id": cluster_id
    },
    "databricks_token": ""
}

cluster_status_dict = {
    "payload": {
        "cluster_id": cluster_id
    },
    "databricks_token": ""
}

search_dict= {
  "action": "run_job",
  "auth_token": "",
  "payload": {
    "job_id": "956"
  }
 }

def write_json(response):
    with open(path + auth_file, 'wb') as file:  
        file.write(json.dumps(response["result"]))


def read_tokens():
    with open(path + auth_file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data


def get_authentication():
    data = read_tokens()
    auth_dict["refresh_token"] = data["refresh_token"]
    auth_response_raw = requests.post(url=auth_url, json=auth_dict, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
    if auth_response_raw.status_code == 200:
        auth_response = auth_response_raw.json()
        if auth_response["status"] == "FAILED":
            logging.info(json.dumps(auth_response_raw.json()))
            status_message = auth_response["error"]["message"]
            raise Exception(status_message)
        else:
            write_json(auth_response)
            logging.info("Successfully got authentication.")
    else:
        logging.info(json.dumps(auth_response_raw.json()))
        raise Exception("Got a bad response.")


def read_databricks_token():
    with open(path + databeicks_token_file, 'r') as infile:
        token = infile.read()
    return token.rstrip()

def check_cluster_status(status):
    data = read_tokens()
    access_token = data["token_type"] + " " + data["access_token"]
    cluster_status_dict["operation"] = "getinfo"
    cluster_status_dict["databricks_token"] = read_databricks_token().rstrip()

    cluster_response_raw = requests.post(url=cluster_url, json=cluster_status_dict,
                                         headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token})
    if cluster_response_raw.status_code == 200:
        cluster_response = cluster_response_raw.json()
        if cluster_response["status"] == "FAILED":
            logging.info(json.dumps(cluster_response_raw.json()))
            status_message = cluster_response["error"]["message"]
            raise Exception(status_message)
        else:
            while cluster_response["result"]["info"]["state"] != status:
                logging.info("Waiting for Cluster to be in "+ status + " status")
                time.sleep(30)
                cluster_response_raw = requests.post(url=cluster_url, json=cluster_status_dict,
                                                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                                              "Authorization": access_token})
                if cluster_response_raw.status_code != 200:
                    logging.info(json.dumps(cluster_response_raw.json()))
                    raise Exception("Got a bad response.")
                else:
                    cluster_response = cluster_response_raw.json()

            logging.info("Cluster is " + status + " now")
    else:
        logging.info(json.dumps(cluster_response_raw.json()))
        raise Exception("Got a bad response.")


def create_cluster():
    data = read_tokens()
    access_token = data["token_type"] + " " + data["access_token"]
    cluster_dict["databricks_token"] = read_databricks_token()
    cluster_response_raw = requests.post(url=cluster_url, json=cluster_dict,
                                         headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token})
    if cluster_response_raw.status_code == 200:
        cluster_response = cluster_response_raw.json()
        if cluster_response["status"] == "FAILED":
            logging.info(json.dumps(cluster_response_raw.json()))
            status_message = cluster_response["error"]["message"]
            raise Exception(status_message)
        else:
            logging.info("Cluster Creation Started")
    else:
        logging.info(json.dumps(cluster_response_raw.json()))
        raise Exception("Got a bad response.")
    cluster_status_dict["payload"]["cluster_id"] = cluster_response["result"]["cluster_id"]
    with open(path + idds_cluster_id_file, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(cluster_response["result"]["cluster_id"])
    check_cluster_status("RUNNING")


def submit_job():
    auth = read_tokens()
    access_token = auth["token_type"] + " " + auth["access_token"]
    create_cluster()
    search_dict["auth_token"] = read_databricks_token()
    job_response_raw = requests.post(url=exec_url, json=search_dict,
                                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token})
    if job_response_raw.status_code == 200:
        job_response = job_response_raw.json()
        if job_response["status"] == "FAILED":
            logging.error(json.dumps(job_response_raw.json()))
            status_message = job_response["error"]["message"]
            raise Exception(status_message)
        else:
            logging.info("Starting to write run id in file")
            run_id = str(job_response["result"]["run_id"])
            with open(path + temp_run_id_file, 'w') as file:
                file.write(run_id)
            return run_id
    else:
        logging.error("Failed to execute Job")
        logging.error(json.dumps(job_response_raw.json()))
        raise Exception("Got a bad response.")


def delete_cluster():
    data = read_tokens()
    access_token = data["token_type"] + " " + data["access_token"]
    cluster_status_dict["operation"] = "delete"
    cluster_status_dict["databricks_token"] = read_databricks_token().rstrip()
    with open(path + idds_cluster_id_file, 'r') as file:
        cluster_id = file.read()
    cluster_status_dict["payload"]["cluster_id"] = cluster_id
    cluster_response_raw = requests.post(url=cluster_url, json=cluster_status_dict,
                                         headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token})
    if cluster_response_raw.status_code == 200:
        cluster_response = cluster_response_raw.json()
        if cluster_response["status"] == "FAILED":
            logging.info(json.dumps(cluster_response_raw.json()))
            status_message = cluster_response["error"]["message"]
            raise Exception(status_message + " " + cluster_status_dict["payload"]["cluster_id"])
        else:
            logging.info("Deleting Cluster")
    else:
        logging.info(json.dumps(cluster_response_raw.json()))
        raise Exception("Got a bad response.")

def check_status():
    with open(path + temp_run_id_file, 'r') as file:
        RUN_ID = file.read()
    os.remove(path + temp_run_id_file)
    logging.info(RUN_ID)
    status_dict["run_id"] = RUN_ID
    status_dict["auth_token"] = read_databricks_token()
    logging.info(status_dict)
    auth = read_tokens()
    access_token = auth["token_type"] + " " + auth["access_token"]
    job_status_response_raw = requests.post(url=exec_url, json=status_dict,
                                            headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": access_token})
    if job_status_response_raw.status_code == 200:
        job_status_response = job_status_response_raw.json()
        logging.info(job_status_response)
    else:
        logging.info(json.dumps(job_status_response_raw.json()))
        raise Exception("Got a bad response.")

    while job_status_response["result"]["state"]["life_cycle_state"] == "PENDING" or job_status_response["result"]["state"]["life_cycle_state"] == "RUNNING":
        logging.info("Waiting for job to finish!")
        time.sleep(30)
        job_status_response_raw = requests.post(url=exec_url, json=status_dict,
                                                headers={"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                                         "Authorization": access_token})
        if job_status_response_raw.status_code == 200:
            job_status_response = job_status_response_raw.json()
            logging.info(job_status_response)
        else:
            raise Exception("Got a bad response.")
    if "result_state" in job_status_response["result"]["state"]:
        if job_status_response["result"]["state"]["result_state"] == "FAILED":
            logging.info(json.dumps(job_status_response_raw.json()))
            status_message = job_status_response["result"]["state"]["state_message"]
            logging.info("Failed with error: " + status_message)
            logging.info(job_status_response)
            delete_cluster()
            check_cluster_status("TERMINATED")
            raise Exception(status_message)
        elif job_status_response["result"]["state"]["result_state"] == "SUCCESS":
            logging.info("Job ran successfully")
    logging.info(job_status_response)
    delete_cluster()
    check_cluster_status("TERMINATED")

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_authentication',
    python_callable=get_authentication,
    dag=dag
)


t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_notebook_job',
    python_callable=submit_job,
    dag=dag
)
t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='check_notebook_status',
    python_callable=check_status,
    dag=dag
)

t1.set_downstream(t2)
t2.set_downstream(t3)
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. Does this code work as expected? We can only review working code, we can't help you debug your code.

Comment: Yes, this is working expected. But as code interacts with internal enterprise APIs there are just accessible within the enterprise network.

Comment: In addition to the 2 down votes that you can see, there has been one vote to close this question. The person that voted to close felt that there needed to be more description about what the program does. Take a look at our help center at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and see if you can add a few details.

Answer (score 1):

### Typo

`databeicks_token_file` -> `databricks_token_file`

### Exceptions

```
        raise Exception(status_message)
```

is going to make it problematic for callers to meaningfully catch this separate from other exceptions, if they need to. Instead, raise a more specific exception, possibly a custom one - they're easy to define in Python.

### Global code

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_authentication',
    python_callable=get_authentication,
    dag=dag
)


t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_notebook_job',
    python_callable=submit_job,
    dag=dag
)
t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='check_notebook_status',
    python_callable=check_status,
    dag=dag
)

t1.set_downstream(t2)
t2.set_downstream(t3)
```

should be pulled into a `main` function.

### Global variables

These:

```
auth_file = "my-token.txt"
idds_cluster_id_file = "my-cluster-id.txt"
path = "/airflow/tokens/"
cluster_id = "0408-000631"
path= "/airflow/tokens/"
temp_run_id_file = "my_save_run_id.txt"
databeicks_token_file= "databricks-token.txt"
auth_url = "https://snapdeal.com/authentication"
cluster_url = "https://snapdeal.com/clustermanager"
exec_url = "https://snapdeal.com/databricksexecutor"
```

are fine-ish where they are, though the names should be capitalized. These might also benefit from being pulled out into a configuration file or environment variables.

However, the rest of it (`args` through `search_dict`) probably doesn't belong here. `args` should just be moved to a nested literal initializer inside the `DAG` constructor; these other dictionaries should be passed - or parts of them passed, where appropriate - between functions. Having various functions mutate various keys in these dictionaries before they're passed to `requests` is not very maintainable. Something like `check_cluster_status` is better off constructing `cluster_status_dict` in its own scope.